# Finding all possible combinations of multiple arrays (where all combinations also include all items in the array)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically, I want to generate all possible combinations of 5 lists, though for simplification I will only go for 3 right now. These are the lists:

```
five=["fivea","fiveb","fivec","fived"] 
six=["sixa","sixb","sixc","sixd"] 
seven=["sevena","sevenb","sevenc","sevend"]
```

But all the solutions I found were combining them in a way where combinations like

`"fivea","sixa","sevena"`

would be allowed. The way I need it though would be a combination where all Arrays stay complete, just in a different order, and none could be left away.

Comment: So you want to pick a value from each array, but don't take a value from the same position in more than one array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't totally clear what your desired outcome is, but I think `itertools.product()` is what you are looking for...

```
from itertools import product

five=["fivea","fiveb","fivec","fived"] 
six=["sixa","sixb","sixc","sixd"] 
seven=["sevena","sevenb","sevenc","sevend"]

my_lists = [five, six, seven]

for item in product(*my_lists):
    print(item)
```

#### Yields

```
('fivea', 'sixa', 'sevena')
('fivea', 'sixa', 'sevenb')
('fivea', 'sixa', 'sevenc')
('fivea', 'sixa', 'sevend')
('fivea', 'sixb', 'sevena')
('fivea', 'sixb', 'sevenb')
('fivea', 'sixb', 'sevenc')
('fivea', 'sixb', 'sevend')
('fivea', 'sixc', 'sevena')
('fivea', 'sixc', 'sevenb')
('fivea', 'sixc', 'sevenc')
('fivea', 'sixc', 'sevend')
('fivea', 'sixd', 'sevena')
('fivea', 'sixd', 'sevenb')
('fivea', 'sixd', 'sevenc')
('fivea', 'sixd', 'sevend')
('fiveb', 'sixa', 'sevena')
('fiveb', 'sixa', 'sevenb')
...
('fived', 'sixd', 'sevend')
```

### Using permutations of all elements...  with shortened lists

```
from itertools import permutations as p

five=["fivea","fiveb"] 
six=["sixa","sixb","sixc"] 
seven=["sevena","sevenb"]

my_lists = [five, six, seven]

# flatten it out...
my_items = [item for sublist in my_lists for item in sublist ]

print(my_items)

for perm in p(my_items, len(my_items)):
    print(perm)
```

Comment: Seems like the OP wanted something where `"fivea","sixa","sevena"` isn't part of the results.

Comment: Yeah, not totally clear....  whether that is "all they did" or whether it was undesirable.  The OP's post isn't too clear.  Anyhow, put a ball in play and see what happens...  perhaps it will stimulate a clarification!

Comment: I see now that I actually didn't make it clear enough. Basically, my desired result was basically one where all elements from each list where included in each permutation. So one permutation would for example be
('fivea','fiveb','fivec','sixa','sixb','sixc','sevena','sevenb','sevenc')

Having thought about it for a while for the result to be achieved, the algorithm would probably need to function like a set of wheels, where for the last row only that row will be permutated, and then for each permutation of any other row, all rows before that will be permutated all the way through as well

Comment: So, you should explore `itertools`.  It has a build in permutation function.  And as you want "all items" included, all you need to do is mash your lists together into a mega-list and then permute it...  See my edited answer